# How to read a pickled object stored in a json file?

Tags: python, json, pickle

Suppose I do the following:

```
a_list = [[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b']]
foo_file = 'foo.json'
open(foo_file, 'wb').write(pickle.dumps(a_list))
```

How can I recover `a_list` from `foo_file`? I ran across this in a github program. I have no idea why the author stored the data that way, but I can't figure out how to read it. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a JSON file. The extension is a lie. That's just a pickle stored with a misleading file extension.

Read it like any other pickle:

```
with open('foo.json', 'rb') as f:
    data = pickle.load(f)
```

Comment: user2357112 Thank you but the code didn't work. "pickle.load" gave "UnsupportedOperation: read" and "pickle.loads" gave "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not '_io.BufferedWriter'".

Comment: @arsinniusyahoocom: Whoops, accidentally opened the file in write mode. Fixed.